# Akka stream fails when throttled

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm using Akka Streams to stream lines of text from a file. All I'm trying to do currently is print each line to stdout. I'm able to get this working without any throttling, i.e. all the lines print to stdout immediately. But when I try to throttle the stream, for example printing 1 line per second, the stream appears to cancel after printing the first  line to std out.

```scala
object FStream {

  // Make config implicit.
  implicit val conf = ConfigUtils.loadAppConfig[ArrivalsAppConfig]("arrivals")

  import AkkaStreamUtils.defaultActorSystem._

  // Source of raw data
  def rawDataStream(path: String): Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = {

    val file = Paths.get(path)

    val ioRes: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = FileIO.fromPath(file)

    ioRes
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val eSource: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = 
      rawDataStream(conf.eventsFilePath)

    val eFlow = 
      Flow[ByteString]
        .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), 10000))
        .map(bs => bs.utf8String)
        .throttle(1, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.shaping)

    val eSink = Sink.foreach(println)

    eSource.via(eFlow).runWith(eSink)
  }
}
```

#### Input File

```bash
James
Is
My
First
Name
```

#### Expected Result

```bash
$ sbt run
James # 0s
Is    # 1s
My    # 2s
First # 3s
Name  # 2s
```

#### Actual Result

```bash
$ sbt run
James # 0s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main method is not waiting for the stream completion.

`runWith` with a `Sink.foreach` gives you a `Future` that you need to await on:

```scala
val f = eSource.via(eFlow).runWith(eSink)

Await.result(f, 10.seconds)
```

See documentation at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Sink/foreach.html

> The sink materializes into a `Future[Done]` which completes when the stream completes, or fails if the stream fails.