# Code not working for FileTailSource in akka Stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I have a log file that is fed data about every visit for some websites ( it is actually just a python programm that simaulates this ) , i want to count the number of visits per websites .
So i m trying to use `FileTailSource` but it doesnt print anything to the file
Can u help?
Tahnks
`

```
import akka.actor._
import akka._
import scala.concurrent._
import java.nio.file._
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import akka.util.ByteString
import java.nio.file.Paths

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{FileIO,Flow, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.alpakka.file.scaladsl.FileTailSource
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import java.lang

object LogFileAnalyzer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Create actor system and materializer
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("LogFileAnalyzer")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    // Read the log file as a source of lines
    val logFile = Paths.get("./src/main/scala/log-generator.log")
    val source =   FileTailSource(logFile,maxChunkSize = 4096,startingPosition=0L,pollingInterval = 250.millis).via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 4096, allowTruncation = false)).map { line =>
      val fields = line.utf8String.split(" ")
      val website = fields(2)
      (website,1)
    }.groupBy(8,_._1).mapConcat()
    .reduce { (entry1, entry2) =>
    val (website1, visits1) = entry1
    val (website2, visits2) = entry2
    (website1, visits1 + visits2)}

    .map { case (website, count) => s"($website, $count)" }
    .map(s=>ByteString(s))



    // Parse each line of the log file to extract the website name
    //val websiteFlow = Flow[ByteString]
    
  
val sink = FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("./f.txt")) 
    // Group the website names and count the number of visits for each website
    //case (website, visits) => (website, visits +1)
    source.to(sink).run()
}
 
}
```

`

when i worked with `FileIO.fromPath` the code worked fine but it runs one time and doesnt process new streamed data
i located the problem and i think it has something to do with the groupby or reduce functions

Comment: Your main method does not wait for anything and thus your program terminates immediately - see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74737002/akka-stream-fails-when-throttled

Comment: Doesnt work either , the problem i guess is in the reduce function because when i comment it the code works , it doesnt ofc pproduce the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem (besides the fact that your main method does not wait for your stream to complete and thus your program will terminate too early) is:

`reduce` only emits a single value when the stream completes ([emits when upstream completes](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html#reduce%5BT%3E:Out%5D(f:(T,T)=%3ET):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BT%5D)), but the stream will never complete because `FileTailSource` will keep polling for new lines of the input file forever.

You might want to use [scan](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html#scan%5BT%5D(zero:T)(f:(T,Out)=%3ET):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BT%5D) instead of `reduce` (because `scan` will emit a new item whenever a new item is received from upstream).

Comment: It solves the issue , but not quite what i am looking for , i have  now as many duplicates as there is counts of website, appreciate your help though let me know if u know any ressource that would help , thanks.